# Using UpdateCursor in the same loop as SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-2.7

I have 2 layers, one with land plots and one with hazard zones.
I want to iterate through the layer with land plots and for every plot I want to add 2 (or 3, depending on some variables) fields. Then I calculate the data for these fields, based on the attribute values of the overlapping hazard zone, and fill it in, in the new fields. I'm trying to do this by using the searchcursor to iterate through the plots and get their geometry (I need the geometry to decide if they overlap, touch, intersect etc. with the hazard zone, which affects the calculated data for the new fields).

Next to all this I try to create an updatecursor and loop through both cursors at the same time using zip(), to update the newly created empty fields immidiately after calculating their proper value.

I'm trying to do this in 1 for loop to save time by only iterating the plots once. 
But the UpdateCursor doesn't work properly. The 2 new fields are Null for all plots except the last plot, that one has the proper values.

Any clues to what is happening here?

I have printed the variables which should be added and they are not Null.

Start of the loop:

```py
        fields_og = arcpy.ListFields(outLayer)
        fields = ['SHAPE@']
        for field in fields_og:
            fields.append(field.name)
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outLayer, fields) as features:

            if atype == 'SHORT':
                arcpy.AddField_management(outLayer, attrn, atype, 10, 0)
            elif atype == 'DOUBLE':
                arcpy.AddField_management(outLayer, attrn, atype, 10, 2)
            else:
                arcpy.AddField_management(outLayer, attrn, atype)

            attrn_s = attrn + "_s"
            minmax_s = attrn + "_mm"
            arcpy.AddField_management(outLayer, attrn_s, 'TEXT')
            out_fields = [attrn, attrn_s]
            minmax = False
            if len(a_minmaxfield) > 0:
                arcpy.AddField_management(outLayer, minmax_s, 'TEXT')
                minmax = True
                out_fields.append(minmax_s)

            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outLayer, out_fields) as cursor:

                for feature, row in zip(features, cursor):
```

After some calculations etc. I want to update like this:

```py
                    if minmax:
                        attrs.append(c)

                    if minmax:
                        row[-3] = val2add
                        row[-2] = b
                        row[-1] = c
                    else:
                        row[-2] = val2add
                        row[-1] = b

                    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: This is not a valid flow of control construct. You can't reprocess the search cursor once it's empty. Instead, cache the values you need from the SearchCursor in a dictionary or list *once*, then make one pass though the UpdateCursor.

Comment: @Vince What do you mean by "You can't reprocess the search cursor once it's empty."? I already started separating the two cursors because it clearly doesn't work but I don't entirely understand why it doesn't. I don't have much experience yet with ArcPy.

Comment: My thinking was just that it would save some time because I only had to iterate the plots once instead of twice. BTW saving them in a list in SearchCursor and accessing the list in UpdateCursor works.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are trying to do. Please describe the task in better detail. I Think you are missunderstanding what a cursor does. For example you are trying to iterate over each row in the attribute table, trying to add the same field for each row. Why use the SearchCursor to add fields? This cant be what you want.

Comment: @BERA That could definitely be the case as I'm quite new to ArcPy. I updated the question with more explanation. Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you trying to use the SearchCursor on the same layer as the UpdateCursor and iterate over these at the same time? You should only need the updatercursor. But I would recommend using Spatial Join instead of trying to compare geometries using nested cursors. Then when you have the hazard zone attributes joined to the plots use Field Calculator or UpdateCursor to calculate your fields by some logic.

Comment: @BERA I'm using SearchCursor to iterate through the plots and get the geometry of the plot. I use the geometry to check if the plots overlap/touch/etc. the hazard zone. If there is a way to only use UpdateCursor, get the geometry and update the row all in 1 loop then that would be great, but I haven't found it yet. When you use spatial join

Comment: @BERA What you suggest is using Spatial Join on the entire layer of plots and add the attributes of the hazard zones but I'm not sure that the way I add them is possible with a Spatial Join. The user has also selected an aggregate type e.g. count to count the amount of hazard zones which intersect/overlap/etc. If the plot instersects 1 hazard zone the added fields will be: 1; 'str with some attrib value from hazard zone' (field is also user selectable).

Comment: @BERA Another thing you should know is that before all of this the user has defined one or multiple filters for the hazard zones to only select a few of them (e.g. flooding hazard every 30 years). So I can't just use a Spatial Join for the entire layer. I know it's all a bit chaotic but I didn't write the original script either. I just have to translate it from QGIS to ArcMap.